# Restoring an EBS Volume to get a functional server up

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I created a 'functional' simple standalone web-server on an ec2 instance backed by a 20GB EBS Volume. This volume is the root drive for the Linux server and hosts MySql, Apache and Tomcat.

Now, I shut this 1st instance down (didn't kill the EBS Volume) and want to use this Volume to get another web-server up (on a new EC2 instance). Even if I attach this volume as 2nd volume in the new EC2 instance, I don't get the webserver running, for obvious reasons.

Is there a way of making this volume as the primary disk volume so that I can start the webserver and other processes as is without having to set them up again?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a snapshot of the instance and [launch a new instance from the snapshot](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-launch-snapshot.html).

Comment: This is basically what you get when you create an AMI.